# Program to search string from multiple files in C programming

Tags: c, string, file, search

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int Search(char *argv[], int n) {
    FILE *fp1;
    int line = 1, flag = 0, i;
    char temp[500];
    char *str=argv[1];
    
    for (i = 1; i < n - 1; i++) {
        fp1 = fopen(argv[i + 1], "r");
        if (fp1 == NULL) {
            printf("could not open the file");
            exit(1);
        }
    }
    
    while (fgets(temp, 500, fp1) != NULL) {
        if ((strstr(temp, str)) != NULL) {
            printf("\n\nA match found on line: %d\n", line);
            printf("\n%s\n", temp);
            flag++;
        }
        line++;
    }
    
    if (flag == 0)
        printf("\nSorry, couldn't find a match.\n");
    else
        printf("occurence of the word '%s' = %d\n", str, flag);
    fclose(fp1);
    return(0); 
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int result;

    if (argc < 3 ) {
        printf("Usage: searchInfile.exe <string> <file> \n");       
        exit(1);
    }

    result = Search(argv, argc);
    if (result == -1) {
        printf("Error number = %d\n", errno);
        exit(1);
    }
    return(0);
}
```

So I have made this short C program to search a string from my files with command line arguments. It is working partially but I cannot figure out where did I go wrong...

Whenever I search one single file it gives correct output when I search two files it shows this error:

```
PS F:\PROGRAMMING\stuff\SSE> .\FileHandle1.exe the test.text test2.txt
could not open the file
```

Here's the link to the code and the whole setup :: http://127.0.0.1:5500/SSE/

Comment: @Nina tried but it won't even show result of 1st file then :(

Comment: Okay let me see what it might be

Comment: Make the system help you: `fp1 = fopen(argv[i + 1], "r"); if (fp1 == NULL) { perror(argv[i + 1]); ...`

Comment: If you use a consistent indenting and formatting, as I just did with your code, you will see at least one problem: You are trying to open all files in a loop without reading each file in between. So only the last file will get searched. -- But this is not the error. Since the message comes only when `fopen()` fails, I assume that "test2.txt" does not exist.

Comment: Oh, the link you post at the end points to "localhost", which is everyone's local computer. This is not what you meant, for sure.

Comment: @thebusybee bussybee yah i made mistake over there !! but my issue is solved now thanks to #Nina

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made some adjustments to the previous code along with adding the search code.
This will open the correct file and read 1 character at a time until the word is found, then move onto the next file.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
void locate(int argc,char* argv[]){
    for(int n = 2; n < argc;++n){
        FILE* file = fopen(argv[n], "r");
        if(file){
            printf("opened %s\n",argv[n]);
            //insert your word search here
            char buffer[1024] = {0};
            char* pointer = buffer;
            size_t offset = 0;
            while((offset = fread(pointer, 1, 1, file))>0){
                
                if(strstr(buffer, argv[1])){
                    printf("%s found in %s\n",argv[1],argv[n]);
                    break;
                }else{
                    
                }
                pointer+=offset;
            }
            fclose(file);
        }else{
            printf("Failed to open file %s\n",argv[n]);
        }
    }
}
int main(int argc,char* argv[]){
    if(argc<3){
        return -1;
    }
    locate(argc, argv);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In what sense? IS it not opening multiple files or is it not locating your word? You weren't clear on what your error is.

Comment: actually the thing is that My argv[1] is going to be the string which i want to search and My argv[2] and so on will be my files in which i want to perfrom the search operation... above solution u gave is helping me to open the files succefully without an error.. but showing me this eroor                                                                          PS F:\PROGRAMMING\stuff\SSE> ./FileHandle1.exe test.txt test2.txt 

Sorry, couldn't find a match.

Comment: You didn't give the program a word to search for. You just gave it file names.

Comment: @yah thanks i didnt notice that before but still                                                                 
            PS F:\PROGRAMMING\stuff\SSE> ./FileHandle1.exe the test.txt test2.txt
could not open the file the

Comment: @SamarthShinde look at the adjusted code. It should work as intended now.

Comment: Thankk so so so much !! really appriciated !!! you are saviour ;)